# Stripe sign up button only works sometimes on mobile

Tags: ios, wordpress, stripe-payments

I have a sign up button on my site that is supposed to re direct to a separate stripe checkout page.  It works on browser, but only works sometimes on mobile.  I've tried it on different iOs versions, with and without wifi, etc.  There seems to be no correlation.  I'm wondering what the issue may be?  The site is set up on a custom wordpress template divi.
http://flutter.buzz

This is the error message

[image: error message]
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: "Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message "you cannot set id to an empty string" we inteperet empty strings as Null in request."  I used the chrome dev tools to inspect the mobile version as well and couldn't find any issues.